# bash script parameters problem

Tags: bash, parameters, if-statement

i can't figure out, where is the problem

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ "$1"=="-h" ]; then
            help
    else
            echo "bad parameter, if you put only one parameter, you can choose only -h"
    fi
```

no matter what i give it as first parameter, script never gets to the else part and every time it is displaying help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
if [ "$1" = "-h" ]
```

Comment: see [bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) for more help (many pitfalls regarding the `test` or `[` command).

Comment: @sevdah: You should click the check mark by this answer to indicate that it solved your problem.